# Model Item with space can not be used as href. IN MVC List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am very new in MVC so be kind and let me know if I am asking something silly .

**What I want:**
In index view I want to have one column which can be used to open document listed.(Since this listing is related to upload document section) 
I have used `<a>` tag for it.

**The problem I am having**:
I am not able to get full name of any document (if document name contains space). So I am not able to provide href attribute in such case.

Here is my View look.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
       <td>
         @{
        var FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ViewBag.CommonFolderPath + ViewBag.UploadFolderName), **item.DocumentName**);
          }
         <a target="_blank" href=@FilePath> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentName)</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Note: Please Note that I am having problem with `item.DocumentName` to get document name when Document name have spaces (Then it only shows first word of document name as document name).

When using `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentName)` it's showing name without any issue.

Comment: show us your controller code, or the model from where you are getting the loop.

Comment: There certainly should be quotes around the value of the `href` attribute; but really need to see where `FilePath` is set. Generally in MVC use MVC to create URLs and anchors: this will mean routes are taken into account (eg. `@Html.ActionLink("Text, "Action", "Controller", new { param = value })`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the `href` attribute in `""` to ensure that any spaces in it will not interfere with the markup that you are generating:

```
<a target="_blank" href="@FilePath">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentName)
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, its working now thanks i just used "" as you suggested.

Comment: This was really helpful. I had a problem with spaces in a file path. I didn't think this would work, but it did! I thought that the @ would be ignored with quotes around it which would have caused me problems. My code ended up like this: <code><a href="@Html.Encode(string.Format("file:{0}",  attachmentItem.Location))">@attachmentItem.Location</a></code>